# How to parse php array response

Tags: php, arrays

I Need to parse the below array and retrieve values;status,id.

Below is the PHP Array

```
Array ( [0] => Post201Response Object ( [container:protected] => 
Array ( [links] => Post201ResponseLinks Object () 
        [id] => 6212588543  
        [status] => AUTHORIZED
```

Below is my php code

```
$status = $apiResponse[0]->links->status;
print_r($status);
```

But I keep on getting a notice 'Trying to get property 'status' of non-object'

Comment: `$apiResponse[0]` is an object, as the dump is telling you. Research the `Post201Response` class and find methods to access these properties (you won't be able to do so directly, because they're protected).

Comment: The object has a protected property `container`, so as @El_Vanja states you'll need the `Post201Response ` class that has a getter or way to retrieve it.